# onHover change image using image-map

Tags: html, imagemap

My JS Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/j6cAu/**

HTML:

```
            <div style="text-align:center; width:330px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                <img id="Image-Maps_8201306061020497" src="http://www.interfaithmedical.com/skillsets_bw.png" usemap="#Image-Maps_8201306061020497" border="0" width="330" height="330" alt="" />
                <map id="_Image-Maps_8201306061020497" name="Image-Maps_8201306061020497">
                    <area shape="poly" coords="172,165,311,120,325,100,313,102,299,78,280,52,259,37,242,27,222,18,189,12,173,12,171,89,172,154," href="http://www.pz.com" alt="CSS" title="CSS"   />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="174,172,260,288,281,297,274,288,301,259,320,224,327,189,328,159,320,125,249,149," href="http://www.pz.com" alt="JQuery" title="JQuery"   />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="169,179,258,300,225,319,184,328,150,328,106,321,90,309,79,318,83,293,123,236,165,180," href="http://www.pz.com" alt="HTML" title="HTML"   />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="161,173,71,294,42,270,22,237,11,200,9,164,14,139,4,134,21,128,72,145,149,169," href="http://www.pz.com" alt="GFX" title="GFX"   />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="164,165,19,118,35,80,60,50,97,28,150,13,150,2,164,20,163,123," href="http://www.pz.com" alt="PHP" title="PHP"   />
                </map>
            </div>
<img src="http://www.interfaithmedical.com/skillsets.png" />
```

What I am looking to do is change the part of the image based on the user mouseover action. So let's say for example the user hover their mouse over CSS the CSS portion of the color image should fade in and the black&white should fade out and on mouse out the color image should fade out and the black&white image should fade in. Is that possible?

My guess is, put the black&white image directly on top of the color and use JQuery to complete the swap?

**SOLUTION**:

```
<HEAD>
<script src="http://www.outsharked.com/scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<BODY
                <img id="circle" src="theImages/skillsets_bw.png" border=1 usemap="#circle" alt="circle">
                <map id="circle" name="circle">
                    <area shape="poly" coords="73, 296, 165, 172, 24, 126, 1, 132, 2, 135, 12, 139, 8, 162, 8, 187, 12, 210, 21, 234, 33, 257, 48, 276, 61, 289" href="http://www.pz.com" alt="GFX" title="GFX" />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="82, 293, 169, 174, 260, 300, 238, 314, 209, 326, 184, 329, 161, 330, 131, 326, 106, 319, 89, 309, 83, 320" href="http://www.pz.com" alt="HTML" title="HTML" />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="321, 123, 327, 149, 329, 180, 325, 208, 315, 238, 303, 260, 276, 287, 284, 296, 258, 290, 173, 171" href="http://www.pz.com" alt="JQuery" title="JQuery" />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="20, 117, 164, 165, 165, 18, 151, 0, 150, 12, 127, 15, 102, 23, 71, 41, 49, 61, 30, 88" href="http://www.pz.com" alt="PHP" title="PHP" />
                    <area shape="poly" coords="172, 43, 172, 165, 311, 120, 325, 100, 312, 104, 301, 80, 284, 59, 263, 40, 240, 26, 216, 17, 189, 12, 171, 11" href="http://www.pz.com" alt="CSS" title="CSS" />
                </map>

<script type="text/javascript">
opacity = 0.9;
</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
opacity =  0.1;
</script>
<![endif]-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#usa').mapster({
        fillOpacity: opacity,
        render_highlight: {
            fillColor: '2aff00',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        render_select: {
            fillColor: 'ff000c',
            stroke: false,
            altImage: 'theImages/skillsets.png'
        },
        fadeInterval: 50
    });
});
</script>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/), a jquery plugin that does this sort of thing out of the box.

Your example using ImageMapster: http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/shbjk/

```
$('#Image-Maps_8201306061020497').mapster({
    render_highlight: {
        altImage: 'http://www.interfaithmedical.com/skillsets.png'
    }
});
```

If you're interested in the technique, the javascript code that does the drawing on a canvas is [here](https://github.com/jamietre/ImageMapster/blob/master/src/graphics.js).

Comment: Here's my link: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/pz/index.htm but it has an error. Not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: You need to download & include the imagemapster script in your project, the same way you've got "theScriptsStyles/imageHover.js" included as a `script` element. Download link on the home page: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

Comment: Ok sounds good. The imageHover was that script but thinking I did something wrong, I linked directly to outsharked.com script but now it's doing something else. Please see my web link in the previous comment.

Comment: Also even though it's not working at all in IE it does somewhat works in FF/Chrome, so I am guessing it's not IE compatible?

Comment: It works in IE, but the specific feature of using an alternate image does not because IE6-8 doesn't support canvases. It will still highlight using a fill color effect. In looking at your link I think the problem is just CSS, the effects are not rendering in the right place. If you have styles applied to the image, try moving them to a wrapper, e.g. `<div style="..." class="..."> <img src="..."> </div>` -- because imagemapster needs to do a lot of specific positioning on the image, it doesn't alwasy work right if there are already styles applied to it.

Comment: .. actually I looked at the source on your page and I don't see any extra CSS on your image that would mess this up -- so I'm not sure why it isn't working right, i'll see if I can find an answer

Comment: :) I figured as the webpage is still brand new in the making. I will wait. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I think that's why the images were coming up as black white in IE but in Chrome and FF it was coming up correctly but in the wrong place.

Comment: Jamie, I took the code and the link you provided and re-coded some of the existing lines and was able to make it work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's great - I had a busy Friday so couldn't get back to it, how did you get it working? Do I still need to look for a bug?

Comment: What I did was, look at the documentation and did some coding of my own. I will post it on my question so you can see. Of course without your help I wouldn't have gotten anywhere! Thanks. I coded it so the IE also works and doesn't look messy! Too bad I cant add you as friend, you are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cut the colored image into the parts defined by your map.
The resulting parts naturally got to have a transparent background.
Position them over the black and white image and set the attribute "display" to "none".

OR
If you're able to use HTML5 position a canvas over your image and load the colored image parts directly into the canvas element.

Comment: Well I cut slice the colored images first and then convert them to B&W but how would I put them together in a circle?
CANVAS idea sounds good... any direction to start?

Comment: Compute the offset of a rectangle, because every single element is a box in the browser. I have to do the math myself, too, so I can't post it yet.

Comment: I never used canvas myself. But a good start would be http://www.html5rocks.com/en/search?q=canvas. Have fun and don't forget to post your result when succeeded ;)

Comment: Ok I will wait... Meanwhile I will see what else I can find. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe to find time for that in close future. But take a pen and a paper, draw the concept and you will find that's just simple logic and math ;)