# How to display part of an image over another image (revealing the background) using jquery and animate

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a project which requires an image of a car to be filled with colour to represent the progress in terms of % complete of a repair, bit like a loading gif but only upto a % completed that I will set when the page loads. To do this across all browsers I have used jquery and animate, with one image (car with no colour) as a background image and another image (car filled with colour) over the top of it. On page load I am trying to reveal part of the coloured image to create the effect of the car being filled in. This works fine but after the animate has finished the full image is shown whereas I want it to stop where the animation stops. My code is below.

Any help would be great, as I have searched high and low for something similar on google but cant find the answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>repair progress</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
        <style type='text/css'>
            li#home {
                background: url('carnotfilledin.jpg') no-repeat;
                z-index:-1;
                width: 214px;
                height: 398px;
            }
            #home a{
                display: block;
                padding-top:0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 0px;
                position:relative;
                left:0px;
                top:-20px;
                left:-2px;
            }
            img.hover {
                display: none;
                width: 214px;
                height: 398px;
            }
            .nav {
                background-color:#292929;
                padding:20px;
            }
        </style>

        <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
            $(window).load(function() {

                $('img.hover').css('display', 'block');
                $('#home a').animate({height: '20%'}, 2000);
            });//]]>  
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="home"><a href="newpagelayout4.html"><img src="carfilledin.jpg" class="hover" ></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possibly you could use IMageMapster, too, so have a look: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965199/onhover-change-image-using-image-map/16965384?noredirect=1#comment24502141_16965384

Comment: thanks for your help, I will have a look at that, was hoping I was 90% of the way there with my code and I was missing something simple